# In susan Benchmark, I am not able to print the value of variable I want?

Tags: c, linux, benchmarking

IN Susan benchmark:
Input to the benchmark is : Image
Output of the benchmark is :Image

I inserted a few functions to perform a few calculations. I want to see their final value after successful run of benchmark. I used

`printf("countervalue %d",counter)`  and

`printf(stderr,"countervalue %d",counter)`

in program, but I couldn't see the output anywhere. While output image is fine. Please tell me how to explicitly print value of variable during run.

Comment: Instead of `printf(stderr,"countervalue %d",counter)`, use `fprintf(stderr,"countervalue %d",counter)`  (note `f`).

Answer (score 1):

1. `printf("countervalue %d",counter)`

The first usage is correct.

2. `printf(stderr,"countervalue %d",counter)`

If you write as above, you should get compiler error, since there is no matching function in standard.